# Verifying a Limit Using Epsilon-Delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm being asked to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{a}{1+a},\;a\neq-1$

So I have to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all x in the domain, $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{a}{1+a}|<\varepsilon$

Now $|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{a}{1+a}|=|\frac{x-a}{(1+x)(1+a)}|=\frac{|x-a|}{|1+x||1+a|}<\varepsilon$, and we'll come back to here after

Now using $|x-a|<\delta$, I set $\delta = 1$, since this puts $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$, and I get

$a-1<x<a+1$, which gives $a<x+1<a+2$

Now going back to the equation I said I'd get back to before,

$\frac{|x-a|}{|1+x||1+a|}<\varepsilon$

$|x-a|<(|1+x||1+a|)\varepsilon$,

at which point I want the smallest epsilon possible, so I change $|1+x|$ to $|a|$, and get

$|x-a|<(|a||1+a|)\varepsilon$

$|x-a|<(|a^2+a|)\varepsilon$

Now I let $\delta=\min(1, (|a^2+a|)\varepsilon)$

So if $\delta=1$, then

$|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{a}{1+a}|<\frac{\delta}{|1+x||1+a|}<\frac{\varepsilon(|a^2+a|)}{|a^2+a|}=\varepsilon$,

And if $\delta=\varepsilon(|a^2+a|)$, then

$|\frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{a}{1+a}|<\frac{\delta}{|1+x||1+a|}<\delta/(|a||1+a|)= \frac{\varepsilon(|a||1+a|)}{|a||1+a|}=\varepsilon$

and this proves the initial limit.

Is this considered to be a right proof?  I'm asking because there's a different solution from my professor but I want to see if the way I did it is good or not.  Thanks

Comment: For readability, try using \delta and \epsilon for $\delta$ and $\epsilon$

Comment: Ok I'll edit it now, thanks

Comment: Fully edited, it's the symbols now

Comment: Your logic is muddy. Whether or not you actually use the $\epsilon$ bound, you write it down before we know it even exists. For sure, we to play around with the difference quotient $|x/(x+1) - a/(1+a)|$ to see how it can be bounded by $(something)*|x - a|$. But after that, it should be much more transparent and formal, along the lines of: "Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta =$some expression involving $\epsilon$. Then ..."

Have a look at how your prof and/or tutors write out the proof. There's a certain art to it and it's worth imitating for a while.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, and I agree it's not the most organized of proofs.  My issue is that they made |x+1|=|a+1|/2, and I want to verify that my choice of |x+1| is valid, because honestly I don't know how to on my own come to that conclusion for |x+1|.  I will take what you said into consideration and follow the logic more like I see in the solutions, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument works fine for $a>0$, since then $a<x+1<a+2\implies|a|<|x+1|\implies\frac{1}{|x+1|}<\frac{1}{|a|}$, which is what you are using.

There are some problems, though, when $a\le0$:

For one thing, your $\delta=0$ when $a=0$, and

it is no longer necessarily the case that $\frac{1}{|x+1|}<\frac{1}{|a|}$ when $a<0$.

For example, if $a=-2$ and $x=-1.2,\;\;$ then $|x-a|<1$  but $\frac{1}{|x+1|}=5>.5=\frac{1}{|a|}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Now what would be the best approach in fixing this?  I understand the logic you're saying, I had a feeling that my application of the absolute value signs after wouldn't work.  My issue when doing these problems is choosing the delta that you pointed out is incorrect.  I feel as if that when I see that choice of delta, it comes out of nowhere. Is there a good approach to choosing delta?

Comment: This is probably easiest to explain with a picture, but since I don't know how to include one, I will try to describe this in words.  We want to get an upper bound on $\frac{1}{|x+1|}$, which corresponds to getting a lower bound on $|x+1|$.  Since $|a+1|$ represents the distance from $a$ to -1, we can arrange to have $\delta\le\frac{1}{2}|a+1|$.  Then if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, the distance from x to -1 is greater than $\frac{1}{2}|a+1|$; so $|x+1|>\frac{1}{2}|a+1|$.

Comment: Another way to do this is to use the triangle inequality:  If $|x-a|<\delta$, then using the reverse triangle inequality gives $|a+1|-|x+1|\le\left||a+1|-|x+1|\right|\le\left|(a+1)-(x+1)\right|=|a-x|=|x-a|<\delta$, so $|x+1|>|a+1|-\delta$.  (Now arrange, say, that $\delta\le\frac{1}{2}|a+1|$.)

Comment: Ok I understand what you're saying completely, it makes perfect sense, the distance part really makes sense to me.  Now, I just have one last question.  If I were to make δ equal |a+1|/4 instead of |a+1|/2, would it still be valid if the rest of the proof followed the same way?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine; anything  positive and less than or equal to $|a+1|/2$ will work for $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to help me, I understand better now.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad that was helpful.